# How can I find wide diameter clear tubes at a cheap price?

Tags: pipe, pvc, hose, vinyl

I am trying to build a series of tubes for my pet rat to run around the apartment in.  But I need for the tubes to be at least 3'' in diameter, preferably 4'' and I need them to be clear so I can find the rat when I need to. The pipes can be flexible or rigid, and I don't particularly care what material they are made out of so long as it is non-toxic.  Also, the tubes do not have to be perfectly clear.  As long as I can find her when I need to.

Thus far, the best thing I can find is this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered how you'll clean the tubes if the rat defecates in them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this has to do with Home Improvement?  Please have a look at the [faq](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq).